# Is there any analog of XML resources mapping for Java based configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My problem is related to access to resources. To be more specific all my JSP just couldn't get access to JS and CSS (resources). Is there any analog of this XML tag `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/"/>` for Java based configuration?

My configuration class

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.springapp.mvc")
@PropertySource("classpath:names.properties")
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    // other beans
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Founded! I just need to add this method into my config class.

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/");
}
```